# Sums involving KroneckerDelta and multi-term functions

Tags: summation

I'm having trouble getting Mathematica (11.0.1.0, OSX High Sierra) to evaluate the following sum:

$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} f(i) \, g(i) \, \delta_{i,j}$

My code is

```
Sum[f[i] g[i] KroneckerDelta[i, j], {i, 0, Infinity}]
```

The output I was expecting was

```
f[j] g[j] UnitStep[j]
```

but instead I get the original sum. When I remove `f[i]` or `g[i]` from the expression, however, I get the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using assumptions:

```
Assuming[
    j ∈ Integers && j >= 0,
    Sum[f[i] g[i] KroneckerDelta[i, j], {i, 0, Infinity}]
]
```

> f[j] g[j]

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to work -- I just get the sum back.

Comment: @RichardTownsend Seems like this was improved in M11.2.

Comment: Unfortunately, my University site licence appears to be stuck at 11.0.1.0. I'll have to find out what the plans are for updating it. But in the meantime, many thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Ok, managed to upgrade to 11.2, and your solution works perfectly. Many thanks again, Carl!